# jquery removes/adds class only once

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover

my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#adminbar").mouseover(function () {  
        $(this).addClass("adm_bar").slideDown("slow");  
    });
    $("#adminbar").mouseout(function () {  
        $(this).removeClass("adm_bar").slideUp("slow");  
    });  
});
```

But when you hover the div with #adminbar, it only adds/removes the class once, if you try to do it again, it wont work. I want you to be able to hover it as many times as you want.
Whats wrong?

Edit: its on the top of the page, [My website(under construction)](http://craftersinn.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like when you use the slideUp, jQuery automatically sets the display to none, so you can't hover an element that doesn't "exist" - it is still there but not "hoverable".

After the slideUp try adding a display : "block" property and visibility: "hidden".

You should be able to hover the element that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with jQuery **[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover)**:

```
$("#adminbar").hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass("adm_bar").slideDown("slow", function() {
    $(this).css({
        visibility : 'visible',
        display: 'block'
    })
  });  
},
function() {
  $(this).removeClass("adm_bar").slideUp("slow", function() {
    $(this).css({
        visibility : 'hidden',
        display: 'block'
    })
  });
```

You need to `visibility: hidden/visible` after animation complete. Because after animation when it hide that it used `display: none` as a result it can't catch the next hover event. So your code is also working.

Comment: This is an offtop. From question text - "adds/removes the class once, if you try to do it again, it wont work"..How your code will resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.hover()` function.

```
$("#adminbar").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("adm_bar").slideDown("slow");  
},
function() {
    $(this).removeClass("adm_bar").slideUp("slow");  
});
```